# Error connecting Ceph OSD to cluster in Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ceph

I'm trying to up Ceph object storage on directory with docker-compose.
Here is what I have for now:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mon:
    image: ceph/daemon:latest
    network_mode: host
    command: mon
    environment:
      MON_IP: 192.168.10.68
      CEPH_PUBLIC_NETWORK: 192.168.10.0/24
    volumes:
      - /etc/ceph:/etc/ceph
      - /data/ceph/:/var/lib/ceph/
  osd:
    image: ceph/daemon:latest
    network_mode: host
    pid: host
    command: osd
    privileged: true
    environment:
      OSD_DIRECTORY: /data/ceph_data/
      OSD_TYPE: directory
      OSD_FORCE_ZAP: 1
    volumes:
      - /etc/ceph:/etc/ceph
      - /data/ceph/:/var/lib/ceph/
      - /dev/:/dev/
    depends_on:
      - mon
  rgw:
    image: ceph/daemon:latest
    network_mode: host
    command: rgw
    volumes:
      - /etc/ceph:/etc/ceph
      - /data/ceph/:/var/lib/ceph/
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - osd
```

But on start (`docker-compose up`) osd fails to connect to cluster with this:

```
mon_1  | debug 2019-10-03 12:36:44.112 7f7782a91700  1 mon.cloyster@0(leader).auth v10 client did not provide supported auth type
osd_1  | [errno 95] error connecting to the cluster
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong? Is there working solution for docker-compose to have Ceph on directory?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the certificates you use

Comment: @LinPy how to setup certificates properly? I haven't seen it in guide, maybe missed

Comment: maybe something related to permission , see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check the Permissions on your `/etc/ceph` it should allow `ceph` to read and write to it, something as `chown ceph:ceph /etc/ceph`

Comment: same after it, seems like.